# How should I approach an unanswered email regarding Job opportunities

Tags: email, networking

I was with a company as a translator and made a solid connection with the other interpreter over the course of a one week trip. We had discussed the possibility of connecting each other in our respective countries, and we kept in touch and have sent cultural gifts back and forth. I recently just brought up the subject of possibly looking for work in their country and a normal prompt responder has now not responded in more than a week.

Should I just drop the subject and assume the question is too sensitive or should I pursue follow-up emails prompting a response.

Comment: Its not really mentioned but is there some possibility that the other interpreter is of an opposite sex? May your email have been misconstrued as an offer to start a more serious personal relationship?

Comment: @RonBeyer I see absolutely no evidence of this being a gender related issue.

Comment: How did you bring up the subject.  The approach means everything.  There is a world of difference between "Wow, I'd love to work in your country, do you have any ideas where I should look?" and "Can you help me apply to a position in your country.  The former is an inquiry, the latter is an imposition.  How exactly did you bring up the subject.

Answer (score 3):

You're pushing too much on a brief and friendly relationship. I meet a lot of people at conferences and exchange a few niceties, and keep in touch. But I'm not about to go off on a limb and help them job search or anything else. It's not that sort of friendship. It's more like a pen pal. I wouldn't answer an email like that either, and if they insisted I'd probably be non committal and write them off as a pest.

Trying to leverage a one week connection isn't the best idea, it would be better for you to job search their country then perhaps mention it to them when you have actually made some progress if at all. I wouldn't try and involve them at all unless they offered first.

Their main friendship for you largely hinges on the fact that you are a non threatening acquaintance from another culture who can be dealt with at arms length.

You should drop the subject. They'll either respond in time or not, leave it up to them.

Answer (score 2):

There's no right or wrong answer.

You could try contacting this person again, and see what happens. Maybe try phoning them instead of e-mailing in order to better judge their attitude?

At the end of the day, however, finding a new job is on ***you***. You'll be far better off getting in touch with a recruiter in that country/area, rather than trying to implicate this relative stranger into your life plans.

After all, would you feel comfortable recommending someone with whom you've only exchanged some gifts, not actually worked together?

If you want to re-establish the connection with this person try simply sending another e-mail saying that yes, you're looking for work in the area, and you'd appreciate some tips, however that you've contacted a recruiter, so not to worry, you're not asking that person for a lot of help. They might write you back at that point ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There is a possibility the email was lost - not delivered, went to spam, got accidentally deleted... As you say, you developed a solid connection, so a quick phone call or a text after a week shouldn't be taken as pushy.

On the call just mention the email and say you are interested, so it would be good if they contact you if there is any opportunity. Don't make them decide on the spot. Your goal is make it easy for them to say "no". Although that wouldn't be a good outcome for you, they would appreciate that and be more willing to contact you in the future.

If few days after the call you get no response, assume he was just being polite and drop the subject.

Comment: downvoter: care to elaborate?